# Go How to check type of product

Tags: parameters, go

I have model `Product` with field `Type`.

Something like this:

```
type ProductType string

var (
    PtRouteTransportation    ProductType = "ProductRT"
    PtOnDemandTransportation ProductType = "ProductDT"
    PtExcursion              ProductType = "ProductEX"
    PtTicket                 ProductType = "ProductTK"
    PtQuote                  ProductType = "ProductQT"
    PtGood                   ProductType = "ProductGD"
)

type Product struct {
    ...
    Type ProductType
    ...
}
```

In `Create` function I have `type` form param:

```
type := req.Form.Get("type")
```

Question: how to check is `type` valid?


Simplest way is:

```
if type != PtRouteTransportation && type != PtOnDemandTransportation && ...
```

but what I supposed to do if `Product` will have 100 types?


How to do this in `go` way?

Comment: What is the type of `type`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really the simplest is to use a map, not as fast as constants but if if you have to test against a large set, it's the most convenient way.

Also since it's pre-allocated, it's thread-safe, so you won't have to worry about locks, unless you add to it at runtime.

```
var (
    ptTypes = map[string]struct{}{
        "ProductRT": {},
        "ProductDT": {},
        "ProductEX": {},
        "ProductTK": {},
        "ProductQT": {},
        "ProductGD": {},
    }

)

func validType(t string) (ok bool) {
    _, ok = ptTypes[t]
    return
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using a type alias to a basic type, why not using a type alias to a *private* type (meaning a struct you cannot initialize outside your package)

See [this example](http://play.golang.org/p/1HehHx-4Ec).

```
type ProductType productType

type productType struct {
    name string
}

var (
    PtRouteTransportation    ProductType = ProductType(productType{"ProductRT"})
    PtOnDemandTransportation ProductType = ProductType(productType{"ProductDT"})
    PtExcursion              ProductType = ProductType(productType{"ProductEX"})
    PtTicket                 ProductType = ProductType(productType{"ProductTK"})
    PtQuote                  ProductType = ProductType(productType{"ProductQT"})
    PtGood                   ProductType = ProductType(productType{"ProductGD"})
)

func printProductType(pt ProductType) {
    fmt.Println(pt.name)
}
func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    // printProductType("test") // cannot use "test" (type string) as type ProductType in argument to printProductType
    printProductType(PtRouteTransportation)
}
```

It means you *cannot* use any other values than the public ones defined in the `var` section.

If you manage to pass a value to the printProductType(`pt ProductType`), your value is *always* a valid one.

---

For the dynamic checking part, that [OneOfOne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/145587/oneofone) addresses [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27251162/6309), I would add a function `GetProductType(name string) ProductType` which:

- check if the name is a valid one
- return one of the official `ProductType` instances defined in the var section above.

That way, the rest of your code always work with an official ProductType value (and not with a 'string' which happens to be matching the right value)

Comment: That wouldn't help with checking.

Comment: @OneOfOne why? How could you pass anything else?

Comment: He's trying to check if `req.Form.Get("type")` is a valid type, he needs to match the string against something.

Comment: @OneOfOne my point is: you don't even have to check: if that compile, it is (statically) checked.

Comment: Either we're mis-communicating or I missed something, it's a dynamic value at runtime, returned from an http handler, it can be anything.